# Permission denied when mounting NFS drive from Pi 3 to Mac

Tags: nfs

I'm trying to share a drive mounted to my Raspberry Pi with my Mac using NFS. The drive is formatted HFS+ so that I can still use it with my mac if need be. I set up the NFS server on my pi using [these instructions](https://www.htpcguides.com/configure-nfs-server-and-nfs-client-raspberry-pi/). My `/etc/exports` looks like this:

```
/mnt/nas   192.168.1.x(rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check,insecure,nohide)
```

Also, the fstab line for the drive looks like this:

```
/dev/sda2      /mnt/nas        hfsplus force,user,umask=0000,nofail   0    0
```

running `exportfs` gets me:

```
/mnt/nas        192.168.1.x
```

Then on my mac, trying `showmount` shows the shared folder and my computer's ip address as well

But then, after trying to mount

```
sudo mount -t nfs -o resvport,rw raspberrypi.local:/mnt/nas /local/folder
```

I get a `mount_nfs: Permission denied` error.

I use ssh keys and am able to mount the drive using sshfs, but I can't get NFS to work. Is HFS+ not compatible, or is there something else I'm overlooking?

Comment: What happens if you run, on your Mac, `showmount -e raspberrypi.local`?

Comment: It shows the directory to be exported as well as my mac's IP address